# is there anyway to inspect the uncalled async tasks queue while i debugging the call stack

Tags: javascript, browser

```
<script>
  function log(x) {
    console.log(x);
  }
  function promiseLog(x) {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => log(x));
  }
  function timeoutLog(x) {
    setTimeout(() => log(x), 0);
  }
  log(1);
  promiseLog(2);
  timeoutLog(3);
  log(4);
  promiseLog(5);
  timeoutLog(6)
  debugger;
</script>
```

after debugger; i can only saw this picture**async call stack**

[image]

but i want to inspect the queue of micro/macro task, just like list

[image]